# How to use hidden attr only on a specific page when is selected

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm using iron-pages. Inside are four elements, one is a grid of cards, and the others are the projects of the cards. Nothing fancy.
Outside of iron pages i've put some navigations buttons (next and previous) with fixed positions.

```
<iron-pages id="pages" class="flex" attr-for-selected="page" selected="{{pageSelected}}">

    <my-grid id="grid" page="grid"></my-grid>

    <page-alpha page="alpha"></page-alpha>
    <page-beta  page="beta"></page-beta>
    <page-gamma page="gamma"></page-gamma>

</iron-pages>

              <!-- Navigation Buttons -->
<div id="controls" class="buttons" hidden$="{{_hideControls}}">
   <button-previous id="previous" on-tap="_goPrev"></button-previous>
   <button-next id="next" on-tap="_goNext"></button-next>
</div>
```

My question is: how to hide in a polymer way the navigation buttons only when i'm in the grid-page ?

I've got some idea but i'm think the syntax is incorrect, or something is missing

```
<script>
 _hideControls: function(){
    if (this.pageSelected = 'grid') {
      this.$.controls.hide();
    } else {
      this.$.controls.show();
    }
}
</srcipt>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
<script>
 _hideControls: function(){
    if (this.pageSelected = 'grid') {
      this.$.controls.hide();
    } else {
      this.$.controls.show();
    }
}
</script>
```

Should be this (also note the added `=` character in the comparison):

```
<script>
 _hideControls: function(){
    if (this.pageSelected == 'grid') {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

And also, this:

```
hidden$="{{_hideControls}}"
```

Should be this:

```
hidden$="{{_hideControls()}}"
```

Why? Because the hidden attribute will be set to true (or rather be kept) if the function returns true. The only time (that I know of) when you use the syntax `_hideControl` instead of `_hideControls()` is when you want a method to be called in response to an event. See below:

```
<div on-tap="_hideControls"></div>
```

**EDIT** To make it update when for example `pageSelected` changes, do this:

```
    <script>
     _hideControls: function(pageSelected){
        if (pageSelected == 'grid') {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
    }
    </script>
```

and:

```
hidden$="{{_hideControls(pageSelected)}}"
```

What happen now is that the method `_hideControls` is ran every time that `pageSelected` is changed. Very convenient!

Comment: Thanks, apparently this only works to hide the controls and doesn't appear again, even if the selected page is changed to another. any ideas?. i'll investigate in the docs a little more

Comment: Yes if you want it to also change back when changes occur you have to  pass `pageSelected` to the method. See edited part of post! :)

Comment: i was digging into this solution, at first didn't work, but then checked twice and i had a type error in my workaround. This works too, i've changed the syntax of the function to be more simplistic to a Conditional (Ternary) Operator:
_hideControls: function(pageSelected){
        return this.pageSelected === 'grid' ? true : false;
      }

Comment: Great that it works! I also noticed that your original post was assigning instead of comparing with the string 'grid' (not sure if that was the typo you mentioned), but I accidentally copied your error into my "working" example and have now updated it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen to `iron-select` and `iron-deselect` event. The event comes with `id` of the item selected (if you have id defined in the html). In your case you can check if the id is `grid` and then do your operations. Also, the _hideControls should be a `Boolean` property. Try below code.

```
<iron-pages id="pages" class="flex" attr-for-selected="page" selected="{{pageSelected}}" 
on-iron-select="onSelect" on-iron-deselect="onDeselect">

    <my-grid id="grid" page="grid"></my-grid>

    <page-alpha page="alpha"></page-alpha>
    <page-beta  page="beta"></page-beta>
    <page-gamma page="gamma"></page-gamma>

</iron-pages>

              <!-- Navigation Buttons -->
<div id="controls" class="buttons" hidden$="{{hideControls}}">
   <button-previous id="previous" on-tap="_goPrev"></button-previous>
   <button-next id="next" on-tap="_goNext"></button-next>
</div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
 onSelect: function(e) {
   if(e.detail.item.id === 'grid') {
     this.hideControls = true;
   }
 }
 onDeselect: function(e) {
   if(e.detail.item.id === 'grid') {
     this.hideControls = false;
   }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah! This seems to work. In my opinion, it's a little complicated just for toogle a class to display none, or set an attribute to an element, but with this i'm ok. Thanks again.